# What's the meaning of "jolly weezer" on the show WW2BAM?

Tags: meaning, slang

A TV presenter of "Who Wants to Be a Millionaire" lamented it would be a "jolly weezer" if the man made less than his wife on a game show.  What did he mean?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149811/discussion-on-question-by-mike-panek-jolly-weezer-meaning-ww2bam); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I suspect that "weezer" has been misheard and, as such, the question is fatally flawed.

Answer (score 2):

One meaning of wheezer is a bad joke - it makes you wheeze instead of laugh.

> noun
> 3. a wheezing breath or sound.
> 4. an old and frequently used joke, saying, story, etc.
> https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wheezer

A possible implication is that it would create a situation that they will never live down.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably not *weezer* but **whizzer** which the OED defines as "Something or someone extraordinary or wonderful; a ‘stunner’. slang."

Their examples range from 1888 to 1977 but it is common for old-fashioned slang to be used for humorous reasons.

While it means a good thing, it could be used sarcastically to mean a bad thing, or it could be taken as a good thing from the point of view of his wife (or even from the point of view of his marriage, i.e. not upsetting his wife).

- Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “whizzer, n.”, September 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/5942914638

Comment: or wheezer, with an aitch. Can refer to a bad joke - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wheezer

Comment: In Britain, a wheeze (n final 'r') is a joke or prank.